# Include navbar on every shtml page phonegap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, shtml

I'm creating a webapp with phonegap where I include a navbar on every shtml page using `<!--#include file="navbar.html" -->`
It works fine when I test it in a browser, but when I build and run phonegap, the navbar is not included. Does anyone know why?

**Update:**
This is my simple index.html code, no funktion is implemented here yet other than including the nav bar:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title> DJKongsy - Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--#include file="navbar.html" -->
</body>
</html>
```

The navbar is created with bootstrap, does that help finding out why it does not work?

**UPDATE 2.0:**

I'm testing Liam's solution here.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-left">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"> <a href="musictab3.shtml">Music</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="abouttab.shtml">About</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="gigs.shtml">Gigs</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a id="userLink" href="logintab.shtml">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
<div id="pageContent">
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
</div>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var user = $.jStorage.get('userInfo');
        if(user.username!=''){
            document.getElementById('userLink').innerHTML=user.username;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('userLink').innerHTML="Log in";
        }
        $( "a" ).on( "click", function( event ){
           // Prevent the usual navigation behavior
           event.preventDefault();
            $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
                var resp = $(data);
                $("#pageContent").html($("#pageContent", resp).html());
                $('#pageContent').load('gigs.shtml #pageContent');
            }); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

How do I make the content from each of the tabs in my navbar appear when clicked? E.g what goes in the div "pageContent"?

The code below works for getting static html info from the page, but it does not run whats in my `<script>` tags. Why?

```
$('#pageContent').load('gigs.shtml #pageContent');
```

Comment: Could you please post your code

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this (I've done it myself) is to have your navbar inside your index.html file (not 'include file') and then use jquery to pull each pages content into your home/main page, it works really well.

So index:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Blahblah
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="pageContent">
            <h1>CONTENT</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and then the script...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "a" ).on( "click", function( event ){
          // Prevent the usual navigation behavior
          event.preventDefault();
               $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
                    var resp = $(data);
                    $("#pageContent").html($("#pageContent", resp).html());
                }); 
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you sure there aren't any simpler and better ideas? This seems like a difficult way of doing a simple thing.

Comment: Simpler? Not so sure. Better? I don't think so. This will also help the speed of your app as its not loading pages and libraries again, just the content in the middle.

Comment: Ok, so I'm trying out your solution. How do I load the data from the different pages into the "pageContent" div. The 'event.preventDefault()' prevents the onClick event from happening, so how does the content change when I click the navbar? See the update in the original question.

Comment: It won't run your scripts again, it only loads what's inside the the pageContent div. Your original question didn't have any scripts, I'm not psychic.